# Every time user logs in the realm object server creates a new realm

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm using synced realm and I'm supporting user login with name and password.

Now the user is able to login and do the stuff but if the same user logs in to another device It will create a new realm and will not get the data from the previous realm. The problem here is every time the user logs in it creates a new realm on the realm object server and it doesn't get the data stored in previous realm. Tried a many ways like changing configurations and other related work around but still no result.

Any idea or suggestion on why there are being created new realms for each user's login where as I'm just logging the user to get the same data from server.

Comment: probably you logged in with different user of different realm name, you track it in realm studio?